# I'm trying to solve ode45 by this expression

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods, ode, runge-kutta

Can I use this form when i need to solve system of ODE by ode45 on MATLAB

```
dy(3)=dy(1)*dy(2)+y(3)*y(2)
```

I mean is my expression correct?

For example how can I solve this:

```
dy(3)=dy(1)*dy(2)+y(1)
dy(2)=dy(1)-y(2)
dy(1)=dy(2)+dy(3)/y(1)
```

initial conditions are :

```
y(1)=1
y(2)=0
y(3)=0
```

Comment: yes , but my question is " is the expression dy(3)=dy(1)*dy(2)+y(3)*y(2) correct " ?? i mean can i put dy(1) on left side and dy(3) right side for example ??

Comment: Why don't you try it and see if it works?

Comment: already I try but nut sure if its work , there is no error but the result not good

Comment: Then post your attempt with code, results and expected results, and explain why the results aren't what you expect.

Comment: I just need ti insure is my code correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATLAB solves ordinary differential equations of the form `dy/dt = f(t,y)`, your differential equation is fully implicit, of the form `f(t,y,dy/dt) = 0`. You can only solve it using `ode15i`. For more information, refer to the documentation on [Ordinary Differential Equations](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/math/ordinary-differential-equations.html) and [`ode15i`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/ode15i.html).

Comment: thanks alot for reply , can you explain more for me with thanks

Comment: Not really, no. Read the documentation, examples are provided. Have a go and if it doesn't work, pose another question, this time with your code, error message and data to make the error reproducible. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for how to ask a good question.